# XPage java class causes com.ibm.designer.domino.napi.NotesAPIException

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

domino version 9.0.1
designer version 9.0.1

(I changed the text of the stack trace slightly to take the customer out of the picture.)

Every once in a while in a developmental environment, I have been getting the following stacktrace in the server log:

```
> 7.01.2014 17:01:13   HTTP JVM: com.ibm.designer.domino.napi.NotesAPIException: File access error:
> Error while getting information on item $FileData
> 17.01.2014 17:01:13   HTTP JVM: Note item not found. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in
> c:/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs
> 17.01.2014 17:01:13   HTTP JVM: Managedbean DatabaseController could not be created Can't instantiate class:
> 'de.holistic.cust.epr.EprDatabaseController'..
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> de.holistic.cust.epr.EprDatabaseController. For more de
> 17.01.2014 17:01:13   HTTP JVM: ailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in c:/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs
> 17.01.2014 17:01:13   HTTP JVM: com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet$ExtendedServletException:
> com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing
> JavaScript computed expression
```

the following from the xml log file does not show any of the promised extra information

```
 com.ibm.designer.domino.napi.NotesAPIException: File access error: Error while getting information on item $FileData Note item not found
```

This exception is also sometimes coupled with a SecurityException.
1. Resigning the database does not do anything
2. changing the classes and xpages and resaving sometimes fixed the issue once, or it was just the time it took me to try that
 
3. restarting the HTTP task / server never makes a differance 
4. cleaning and building does not do a thing.

After google searching for the issue, some people have had this issue while storing their java classes in the java area of the "normal designer" perspective.  I have my java code in a custom source folder "WebContent/WEB-INF/src".

Is anyone else having/had this issue? If so, how can it be best resolved?  Is this a bug in the XPage implementation?  I have not had this issue with java classes in a jar file, only when the source code needs to be compiled.  Although it is a possibility to deliver the application with jar files instead of raw classes, it is impractical in a developmental setting.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I managed to correct the problem temporarily by changing the name of the class listed in the stack trace and then naming it back again.  This seems to me to be a band-aide solution not really correcting the cause.  Is there any way to prevent this from happening again?  Am I doing something wrong to cause this error?

Comment: The best thing to do here is to get IBM support involved to check out this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiled java class is stored in the $FileData item of the design note in which the java source is saved. So the error means the compiled code is lost and not generated by the server. Below are something that I think might help to debug this issue.

1. Open the project view in designer, modify the filter to show the java classes to check if they are available.
2. Check if the java source folder is on the build path.
3. Check the auto-rebuild option.
4. If the development is on local and deployed to the server via design refresh or replace. Check if the classes are lost in this process.

Comment: I'd like to add point 5.  Make sure you are waiting long enough to build your complex application by making note of the really small progress icon in the bottom right corner of designer.  This particular application was taking in the area of 5 minutes to build (dont ask me why).  Because I was not waiting long enough, the local java files were not available for the browser causing the exceptions.

Comment: @Greg The building consists of a lot of progresses. e.g. resume metadata, building, refreshing, initializing. Compared to a classic notes app, the main difference is to retrieve all the design elements and compile the java and ls. If the server where the app resides is not as fast(network) as a local one, it normally takes several minutes to build. If the server is however slow, the building takes forever. So if that's the case, develop and build your app locally and deploy it to the server.